# XCode4 jump bar overcrowded

Tags: xcode, xcode4, pragma

I'm using `#pragma mark - Description` all over my source code to use with the XCode4 Jump Bar. This is a pretty handy feature all most you already know.

But right now I'm having a big .h/.m file containing all my business logic classes (RMCategory, RMProduct, RMCountry, RMAddres, ...) and my jump list is starting to look overcrowded.

Is there any known way to disable some items in the jump list? Specifically, I'm looking into hiding the ivars from the .h jumplist. Is there some directive like `#pragma hide ivars`?

I've been trying to search other supported `#pragma`s specific to XCode but haven't been able to found anything apart from the classic `// TODO`, `// FIXME` et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I've been told by Apple staff at their dev forums that this was currently impossible. I've filed an enhancement proposal there.